# access webcam over javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for my upcoming project i would like to know if there is solution to access the webcam without good old flash. Is it possible to do that in javascript, jquery or any other framework.
Maybe you've an approach for a workaround or something!

any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/navigator.getUserMedia

Comment: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Comment: wim, do you have any expiriences with that? does it work crossover every browser? despite the mobile ones!

Comment: @TedMosby you do know that plugin requires flash, yes?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in HTML5 with the `getUserMedia()` API, but as yet browser support is very limited.

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ for more info.

Note that the user *MUST* explicitly permit access to the camera and microphone, to prevent illicit snooping.

Comment: is this for all browser? and what about the mobile ones? ive heard this would be a problem that it works crossover!

Comment: @TedMosby it's not well supported yet - mostly in the very latest versions of Chrome.

Comment: well thats the problem! i found this article too (i wouldn ask here if google brings up good answers) but it should be able on all standard browsers (gecko, webkit, opera and msie)

Comment: even HTML5 isn't "fully" ratified yet AIUI.  This is a very new feature and the spec isn't final.